# Unix cut command to extract string from left side post 2nd dilimiter from right

Tags: unix, cut

how can the cut command return value left to 2nd last delimiter starting from the right side.

```
$ echo 'qwertyuiop.abcdefgh.1234567890.txt' | cut -d '.' -f 1,2
qwertyuiop.abcdefgh
$ echo 'qwertyuiop.1234567890.txt' | cut -d '.' -f 1,2
qwertyuiop.1234567890
$
```

expected output for both

> qwertyuiop.abcdefgh
>
> qwertyuiop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse your string with the `rev` command and then `cut` from the third field to the end, reversing at the end.

```
$ echo 'qwertyuiop.abcdefgh.1234567890.txt' | rev | cut -d '.' -f 3- | rev
qwertyuiop.abcdefgh
$ echo 'qwertyuiop.1234567890.txt' | rev | cut -d '.' -f 3- | rev
qwertyuiop
```